# Nested if in lisp

Tags: lisp

Hello i am trying to create a nested if in lisp, but we keep getting the error, and we don't know how to fix it!

> ** - EVAL: too many parameters for special operator IF:

```
(defun spread-stones-helper(game-state StoneInHand Player player-index pit-index)

    ;; Do we have more stones in our hand?
   (if (> 0 StoneInHand)
        ;; Are we above the pit limit?
        (if (> pit-index 5)
            ;; Switch the player and reset the pit-index to 0
            (setq player-index (switchplayer player-index))
            (setq pit-index '0)
        )

        ;; Add 1 to the pit
        (set-pit game-state player-index (GetCorrectPit player-index pit-index) (+ (get-pit game-state player-index (GetCorrectPit player-index pit-index)) 1))

        ;; Recursive call the function, with one less stone and 1 up in pit-index
        (spread-stones-helper game-state (- StoneInHand 1) Player player-index (+ pit-index 1))
    )
    ;; There are no more stones in hand, run capture stones
    ;; (captureStones game-state StoneInHand Player player-index pit-index)
)
```

Comment: I think you're probably confusing yourself with the odd paren/indentation style you've created.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In lisp the `if` operator accepts three expressions that are the condition, value in case the condition is true and value when the condition is false... for example

```
(if (< x 0)
    (print "x is negative")
    (print "x is greater or equal than zero"))
```

You can also omit the last expression and in this case it's assumed to be NIL.

If you want to put more expressions in one of the two cases you must wrap them in a `progn` form

```
(if (< x 0)
    (progn
       (print "HEY!!!!")
       (print "The value of x is negative...")))
```

The case of having an `if` expression with only one of the two branches filled and with many expressions was found to be very frequent and therefore two special variations for this exact use were added:

```
(when (< x 0)
    (do-this)
    (do-that)
    (do-even-that-other-thing))

(unless (< x 0)
    (do-this)
    (do-that)
    (do-even-that-other-thing))
```

The `when` form above is equivalent to

```
(if (< x 0)
   (progn
     (do-this)
     (do-that)
     (do-even-that-other-thing)))
```

The `unless` form has the very same meaning but with the condition reversed... in other words it's equivalent to

```
(if (not (< x 0))
   (progn
     (do-this)
     (do-that)
     (do-even-that-other-thing)))
```

To recap you should use `if` only when you need to write code for **both** branches (the true and the false one). Otherwise use either `when` or `unless` depending on what is more readable for your test.

When using an `if` form you must use a `progn` in branches where you need to put more than a single form.

Answer (score 5):

Don't forget to use `(progn ...)` for more than one if-statement

```
(defun spread-stones-helper (game-state StoneInHand Player
                             player-index pit-index)

    ;; Do we have more stones in our hand?
   (if (> 0 StoneInHand)
       (progn
         ;; Are we above the pit limit?
         (if (> pit-index 5)
         (progn
               ;; Switch the player and reset the pit-index to 0
               (setq player-index (switchplayer player-index))
               (setq pit-index '0)))

         ;; Add 1 to the pit
         (set-pit game-state player-index
                  (GetCorrectPit player-index pit-index)
                  (+ (get-pit game-state player-index
                              (GetCorrectPit player-index pit-index))
                     1))

        ;; Recursive call the function, with one less stone and 1
        ;; up in pit-index
        (spread-stones-helper game-state
                              (- StoneInHand 1)
                              Player
                              player-index
                              (+ pit-index 1))))
   ;; There are no more stones in hand, run capture stones
   ;; (captureStones game-state StoneInHand Player player-index pit-index)
   )
```

Answer (score 5):

"if" takes a test and two forms -

You've given the first "if" a test and three forms

Assume (> 0 StoneInHand) is true.

Do you want to run both the second if and the set-pit statements?

If so, you need to wrap them in a (progn )